# Not able to establish VPN connection using SharedSecret

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I'm trying to connect to a vpn using `Swift`. I have created class `VpnHandler` and I'm using Keychain `Swift` to keep keychain reference.
My code look like this:

```
    import Foundation
    import NetworkExtension
    import KeychainSwift
    
    
    final class VPNHandler {

    let vpnManager = NEVPNManager.shared()
    
    func initVPNTunnelProviderManager(serverAdress: String, remoteIdentifier : String, sharedSecred:String) {
        let sharedKey = sharedSecred.data(using: .utf8)
        let keychain = KeychainSwift()
        guard let sharedKey = sharedKey else { return }
        keychain.set(sharedKey, forKey: "shared_secret")
        vpnManager.loadFromPreferences { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            let IKEv2Protocol = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
            IKEv2Protocol.username = nil
            IKEv2Protocol.localIdentifier = nil
            IKEv2Protocol.serverAddress = serverAdress
            IKEv2Protocol.remoteIdentifier = remoteIdentifier
            IKEv2Protocol.authenticationMethod = .sharedSecret
            IKEv2Protocol.disconnectOnSleep = false
            IKEv2Protocol.useExtendedAuthentication = false
            IKEv2Protocol.sharedSecretReference = keychain.getData("shared_secret", asReference: true)
            IKEv2Protocol.passwordReference = nil
            var rules = [NEOnDemandRule]()
            let rule = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
            rule.interfaceTypeMatch = .any
            rules.append(rule)
            self.vpnManager.localizedDescription = "My VPN"
            self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = IKEv2Protocol
            self.vpnManager.onDemandRules = rules
            self.vpnManager.isOnDemandEnabled = true
            self.vpnManager.isEnabled = true
            print("SAVE TO PREFERENCES...")
            self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences { error in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                print("CALL LOAD TO PREFERENCES AGAIN...")
                self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    do {
                        try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
                        print("Starting VPN...")
                    } catch let error {
                        print("can't connect VPN'")
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

When I call the function `initVPNTunnelProviderManager`, the vpn configuration in the phone setting is created. Our app starting connecting to vpn, but then disconnect immediately. When we connect vpn configuration in the phone setting, it's working.
I don't know what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue.
In your server in /etc/ipsec.conf file, replace the following:

```
ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!,aes256-sha2_256
    esp=aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!

With 

ike=aes256-sha2_256-modp2048
esp=aes256-sha2_256
```